# Sizing the Canvas widget with other widgets on the GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm creating a GUI that has a spreadsheet-like interface which is wrapped with entry method to allow the person that uses the program to enter it as if it is on a spreadsheet. This allows me much greater control over all the data and manipulate it for data analysis later. However, I can't restrict the size of the canvas to allow the scrolling bar to take effect. I.E. if I change the number of rows, the canvas will resize to that (along with column(s) changes too). I have other widgets within the GUI that isn't shown in the code but I'm just focusing on trying to force a size on the Canvas widget itself.

Is there a way for me to force the Canvas to stay within "width and height" size without having the rows and columns controlling the size of the Canvas?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from textwrap import fill
from datetime import date

#Instantiate the GUI 
class StartApp(tk.Tk): 
def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    t1 = ExcelTable(self)
    t1.grid(row = 0, columnspan=2, sticky = "N")
    t2 = ProductWidget()
    t2.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky="SW")
    t3 = TotalTrucks()
    t3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
    
 #Instantiate the layout for the excel-like table entry for the top 
part of the GUI
class ExcelTable(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, width=500, height=500):
    
    rows=20
    columns=10
    #label for each column in the table        colHeaders = ["#", "Driver", "Tare", "Ticket #", "Location", "Product", "Gross", "Net", "Tons", "Date"]
  
# use black background so it "peeks through" to 
# form grid lines
    #tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="black", width=150, height=200)

    #attempt to create a scrollbar within a canvas
    canvas = tk.Canvas(parent)
    scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
    
    #contain the Frame within the canvas
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, canvas)

    #creates the widgets to behave like excel-like table for data entry
    self._widgets = []
    for row in range(rows):
        current_row = []
        for column in range(columns):
            if row == 0: #create the headers for the spreadsheet widget, using the colHeaders array
                if column == 0:
                    label = tk.Label(self, text = colHeaders[column], borderwidth=0, width = 4)
                else:
                    label = tk.Label(self, text = colHeaders[column], borderwidth=0, width=10)
            else:
                if column == 0:
                    label = tk.Label(self, text = (row))
                else:   
                    label = tk.Entry(self, text="")
                    label.bind
            label.grid(row=row, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            current_row.append(label)
        self._widgets.append(current_row)

    for column in range(columns):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(column, weight=1)
    
    canvas.create_window(0,0,anchor='nw', window=self)
    canvas.update_idletasks()

    canvas.configure(scrollregion=parent.bbox('all'))
    canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
    scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

def set(self, row, column, value):
    widget = self._widgets[row][column]
    widget.configure(text=value)

def key(event):
    print ("key: {}".format(event.char))

#obtain and store values that are entered in the ExcelTable
def find_in_grid(frame, row, column):
    for children in frame.children.values():
        info = children.grid_info()
        #note that rows and column numbers are stored as string                                                                         
        if info['row'] == str(row) and info['column'] == str(column):
            return children
    return None

class ProductWidget(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, background="white")
        self._widgets = []
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Product")
        label1.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky="nsew")
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Total Tons")
        label2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

class TotalTrucks(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, background="white" )
        self._widgets = []
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Total Trucks")
        label1.grid(row=0, rowspan=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text="Today: ")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0, stick="nsew")
        label3 = tk.Label(self, text="Last Week: ")
        label3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        label4 = tk.Label(self, text="Overall")
        label4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="nsew")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    currYear = date.today().year
    startGUI = StartApp()
    startGUI.title("Truck Log " + str(currYear))

    startGUI.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should use a frame instead of another canvas inside a canvas.  Also put those labels and entries inside the frame instead of the outer canvas.  There are several questions in SO on scrollable frame, so do some research.

Comment: Frame doesn't allow scrolling from what I read so canvas has to be used to create a.scrollable area with a group of widgets. I'll revise the code to have the class revert to a tk.Frame but it's still the same issue when it comes to trying to scroll the canvas widget that contains the label and entry widgets.

Comment: It is not scrolling the frame but the outer canvas to show different part of the internal frame.

Comment: I've tried to put it within the frame but when i switch from "self" to "parent" for the label, it completely messes up the GUI. I've included the full code so you can see it for yourself if you're so inclined. I appreciate your feedbacks!

Comment: You should not call `t1.grid(row = 0, columnspan=2, sticky = "N")` inside `StartApp.__init__()`.  And you need to bind `<Configure>` event on `ExcelTable` to update `scrollregion` of `canvas`. Also you forget to call `canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)`.

Comment: Are you willing to provide a template for me to understand what you may be talking about because I cannot remove the t1.grid outside of the init function and the configure I thought I already did but you seem to be referring to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ExcelTable` is the internal frame inside `canvas` and is already put inside `canvas` using `canvas.create_window(...)`, so you should not call `t1.grid(...)` inside `StartApp.__init__()`.

Also you set the `scrollregion` of `canvas` wrong in the following line:

```py
canvas.configure(scrollregion=parent.bbox('all'))
```

It should be:

```py
canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
```

Finally you forgot to configure `yscrollcommand` option of `canvas`.

Below is the changes required:

```py
...

class StartApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        t1 = ExcelTable(self)
        ### should not call t1.grid(...) since t1 has already put in canvas using canvas.create_window(...)
        #t1.grid(row = 0, columnspan=2, sticky = "N")
        t2 = ProductWidget()
        t2.grid(row=1, column=0,sticky="SW")
        t3 = TotalTrucks()
        t3.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
...

class ExcelTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, width=500, height=500):
        ...
        #canvas.configure(scrollregion=parent.bbox('all'))
        canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'), width=self.winfo_width(),
                         yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        ...
```

Comment: This solved it and I cannot believe how simple it was. Definitely a learning moment for me. Really appreciate your help and sorry for the late reply!